# Why is PostgreSQL ORDER BY and LIMIT with UUID so slow?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a problem with my request. I have a table where the `id` is UUID, and I have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE fk = ?
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

This query runs like 50s, but if I remove the `ORDER BY id`, this query runs in 0.3s. But if I used some `fk` that is also a UUID, `ORDER BY fk` work fast.

Comment: You should mention the approximate number of rows.

Comment: An [MCVE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) would improve this Question.

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for the different SQL statements and the DDL for the table and indexes involved? All in plain text, as an update to your question. Without this information, we only guess what is going on.

Comment: With `order by` Postgres must scan the entire table to find qualifying rows  then sort those entries before choosing the first 5. Without `order by`  Postgres will get the first 5 *random* qualifying rows found. Note: There is no order to how rows are stored. Further, *some FK* implies a join, so those would be totally different queries, it would be best to include that query as well.

Comment: Buffers: shared hit=11230 read=311525 written=15
  ->  Index Scan using risk_objects_pkey on public.risk_objects riskobject0_  (cost=0.43..734262.71 rows=6300 width=133) (actual time=30826.191..42193.966 rows=5 loops=1)
"        Output: id, contract_version_id, device_id, general_agreement_id, insured_person_id, payment_break_downs_id, properties_id, risk_object_index, subject_to_inspection, vehicle_id"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 321520
        Buffers: shared hit=11230 read=311525 written=15
Planning 0.230 ms
Execution 42194 ms

Comment: Buffers: shared read=4
  ->  Index Scan using risk_objects_general_agreement_id_idx on public.risk_objects riskobject0_  (cost=0.43..160830.98 rows=6300 width=133) (actual time=3.216..3.219 rows=5 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (riskobject0_.general_agreement_id = '85924851-8cf6-4703-96d6-f99563b7c167'::uuid)
        Filter: (riskobject0_.insured_person_id IS NOT NULL)
        Buffers: shared read=4
Planning time: 5.429 ms
Execution time: 3.253 ms

Comment: Limit  (cost=0.43..128.08 rows=5 width=133) (actual time=3.218..3.222 rows=5 loops=1) 
count of rows = 10 000 000

Comment: Please read the hundreds of identical questions (that cared to supply some more information) for the cause and for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this little information, I can only guess that the optimizer opts to use the index that supports `ORDER BY` in the vain hope to find enough result rows quickly.

You can disable that strategy with

```
ORDER BY id ASC NULLS FIRST
```

Unless you created the index with `NULLS FIRST`, it is created with `NULLS LAST` by default. But even if there are no NULL values, PostgreSQL won't consider an index created with `NULLS LAST` for an `ORDER BY` clause with `NULLS LAST`.

Comment: do u have any article why this works, because i dont have any null key values, or after disabvling basic strategy, optimizer used best one

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY` clause present in the first query (but not the second) adds an additional sorting step to the query pipeline.  For a moderately large table, this sort can take some time, especially if your query does not have any indexing scheme to make it run faster.  Your current observations are expected.

Comment: But if I used some FK that is also UUID, order by FK work fast